# Scipy Curve Fit: Supplied function does not return a valid float

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Although I visit here often, this is my first post, please excuse me if I don't have the formatting down correctly.

I'm trying to use Scipy Curve Fit on an equation that seems to only be well behaved for a small set of inputs. I can't post images yet, but a link to the basic equation is below. When I attempt to curve fit to that equation, I get "error: Supplied function does not return a valid float". I'm not very experienced with python yet, but I'm guessing that for some reason Curve Fit is taking too large of steps and running into a NaN area?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PaJ3.gif]

I've been working on this problem for a while now and but I've ran out of ideas. Am I doing this wrong or is there another trick/tool that I should try instead?

Here is another link to the notebook on github. If you're interested, scroll down about halfway to the heading "2. Curve Fitting".

https://github.com/JAmarel/LiquidCrystals/blob/master/ElectroOptics/PandaImportExcelSheets.ipynb

Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: I have found [lmfit](http://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/) to be very useful for fitting models which break for certain values of the inputs - it's a lot more robust than the scipy modules. As an aside, you should also use the two-argument [arctan2](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html) if you have a separate numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases it's typically best to start with a small toy problem which reproduces the error.

This specific error is likely coming from [this line](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/minpack.h#L158). While cryptic, it tries to convert the input of your function into an array of floats (NPY_DOUBLE), and throws an error if it fails.

OK, here's how to trigger the error:

```
In [3]: import numpy as np

In [4]: from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

In [5]: x = np.array([1.0, 2., 3, 4.])

In [6]: y = x

In [7]: def f(x, a):                       # try a nan
   ...:     return np.nan
   ...: 

In [9]: curve_fit(f, x, y, 2.0)
/home/br/virtualenvs/scipy-dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py:604: OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
  category=OptimizeWarning)
Out[9]: (array([ 2.]), array([[ inf]]))
```

Nope, `nan`s produce some different output. Let's try a string:

```
In [10]: def g(x, a):
   ....:     return 'nonsense'
   ....: 

In [11]: curve_fit(g, x, y, 2.0)
<snip>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Also different error. OK, let's try a complex number:

```
In [12]: def h(x, a):
   ....:     return 1j
   ....: 

In [13]: curve_fit(h, x, y, 2.0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('complex128') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'
<snip>

error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
```

Bingo. Now I'd start checking if your function wanders into the complex plane for some inputs.